# Applying DRY to Autofixture "Build" statements

Tags: c#, autofixture

Assume I have this concrete class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to create an anonymous instance that has a valid email address, and the fullname field is no more than 20 characters. I can do this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
var anonUser = fixture.Build<User>()
    .With(x => x.Email, string.Format("{0}@fobar.com", fixture.Create<string>()))
    .With(x => x.FullName,  fixture.Create<string>()Substring(0,20))
    .Create();
```

Is there a way that I can define this in one place, so that AF knows that I can get my customized anon class by using:

```
var newAnon = fixture.Build<User>();
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using convention-based customizations as @MarkSeemann suggests in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22333452/26396) to keep your test code DRY. More on the topic [here](http://megakemp.com/2011/12/15/keep-your-unit-tests-dry-with-autofixture-customizations/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have various options. In my opinion, the best option is to apply the [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP) principle of **listening to your tests**. When the test becomes difficult to write, it's time to reconsider the design of the System Under Test (SUT). AutoFixture tends to amplify this effect.

**Refactor to Value Objects**

If you have a requirement that the `Email` and `FullName` properties should have particularly constrained values, it might indicate that instead of [Primitive Obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession), the target API would benefit from defining explicit `Email` and `FullName` **Value Objects**. The [canonical AutoFixture example is about phone numbers](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/05/01/DealingWithConstrainedInput).

**Use data annotations**

You can also use [data annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) to give AutoFixture hints about the constraints of the values. Not all data annotation attributes are supported, but you can use both [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.aspx) and [RegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx).

It might look something like this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression("regex for emails is much harder than you think")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [MaxLenght(20)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Personally, I don't like this approach, because I prefer [proper encapsulation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/Poka-yokeDesignFromSmelltoFragrance) instead.

**Use Customize**

Instead of using the `Build<T>` method, use the `Customize<T>` method:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<User>(c => c
    .With(x => x.Email, string.Format("{0}@fobar.com", fixture.Create<string>())
    .With(x => x.FullName, fixture.Create<string>().Substring(0,20)));
var newAnon = fixture.Create<User>();
```

**Write a convention-driven Specimen Builder**

Finally, you can write a [convention-driven customization](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/Convention-basedCustomizationswithAutoFixture):

```
public class EmailSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request,
        ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        if (pi.PropertyType != typeof(string)
            || pi.Name != "Email")
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        return string.Format("{0}@fobar.com", context.Resolve(typeof(string)));
    }
}
```

This approach I really like, because I can put arbitrarily complex logic here, so instead of having to create a lot of one-off customizations, I can have a small set of conventions driving an entire test suite. This also tends to make the target code more consistent.

Comment: ISpecimenBuilder seems to do the trick.  What is the difference between Customize and Build?  Did you try the above code for Customize?  The compiler doesn't seem to grok it.

Comment: Build is a one-off specialization of the creation algorithm. Customize is reusable. No, I actually didn't try to compile the above code, so I may have missed a parenthesis or similar...